# Laravel and Intervention/Image: Uploading photos to a AWS S3 bucket results in 0 byte files

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, php-7, intervention

I'm using http://image.intervention.io/ with Laravel to resize images before storing them in an AWS S3 bucket. Here is the applicable code:

```
$extension = $image->extension();
$realPath = $image->getRealPath();
$resizedImage = Image::make($realPath) // ->resize(255, 255); // resize or not, make() seems to always return an empty Image
$file_path = "posts/$post->id/images/image-$post->id-num-$pictureCount.$extension/"; 
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($file_path, $resizedImage->__toString(), ['visibility' => 'public']);
```

When debugging (breakpoint on the line `$path` is set) this I can see that `$realPath` holds a value like `/private/var/folders/23/jl2dytp168g9g9s5j51w2m780000gn/T/php9047Fh` - and going there I can see the image that I'm trying to `make()`/`resize()`.

The `$resizedImage` object has the following fields:

```
[encoded] => 
[mime] => image/jpeg
[dirname] => /private/var/folders/23/jl2dytp168g9g9s5j51w2m780000gn/T
[basename] => phpTNRdXe
[extension] => 
[filename] => phpTNRdXe
```

I'm guessing that the encoded property should hold something like the base 64 image data?

When checking the image in AWS S3 bucket, it is always getting uploaded as a image with 0 bytes. What am I doing wrong here?

Intervention is configured to use GD if it makes any difference

Comment: Try saving to a file using save method just for sake of debug, and tell if the saved file contains the desired image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Laravel File class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.1.3/src/Illuminate/Http/File.php) is a subclass of [Symfony File class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.0.5/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php) which in turn subclasses `\ SplFileInfo`

The file object can be passed directly in `Image::make`. `Image::make` [gets the `realPath`](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/2.5.1/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php#L323) for `\SplFileInfo` objects.

Image::make returns an instance of [Image](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/2.5.1/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L360) and `$resizedImage->__toString()` returns the value of its `encoded` field. `encoded` starts out as an [empty string](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/2.5.1/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L84).

The image should be [encoded](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/2.5.1/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L119) before accessing its encoded value.

```
$resizedImage->encode();
```

Then,

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($file_path, $resizedImage->__toString(), ['visibility' => 'public']);
```

Comment: Ah! Fantastic. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question! Edit: I will award you the bounty in 20 hours (seems like SO doesn't allow it to be awarded before then)